# logstash-output-file-as time based

Tags: logstash, filebeat

My output of logstash directed to the file called apache.log.
This file needs to be generated in every hour.

For Example: apache-2018-04-16-10:00.log or something similar to this.

Here my configuration file :

```
# INPUT HERE
input {
    beats {
          port => 5044
    }
}

# FILTER HERE
filter {
    if [source]=="/var/log/apache2/error.log"
    {
        mutate {
            remove_tag => [ "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" ]
            add_tag => [ "apache_logs" ]
        }
    }
    if [source]=="/var/log/apache2/access.log"
    {
        mutate {
            remove_tag => [ "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" ]
            add_tag => [ "apache_logs" ]
        }
    }
}

# OUTPUT HERE
output {
    if "apache_logs" in [tags] {
        file {
            path => "/home/ubuntu/apache/apache-%{+yyyy-mm-dd}.log"
                codec => "json"
        }
    }
}
```

Please help out to solve.

Comment: @ sniperd @Magnus Bäck

Comment: This configuration is not working properly

Comment: You can't tag people in SO.

Comment: You should add what happen when you launch logstash with this configuration and how it does not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the joda-time documentation (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html), you have  `H  hour of day (0~23)`. So output configuration to solve your problem would be:

```
output {
    if "apache_logs" in [tags] {
        file {
            path => "/home/ubuntu/apache/apache-%{+yyyy-mm-dd-HH}.log"
                codec => "json"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine,

   **' # OUTPUT HERE
    output {
    if "apache_logs" in [tags] {
    file {
    path => "/home/ubuntu/apache/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/%{+HH}/apache-%{host}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd-HH-zz}.log"
    codec => "json"
    }
    }
    } '**

Files:

  **' root@ip-192-168-2-79:/home/ubuntu/apache/2018/04/18/07# ls
    apache-ip-192-168-2-196-2018-04-18-07-UTC.log  
    apache-ip-192-168-2-223-2018-04-18-07-UTC.log '**

thanks you guys

Comment: @MohamedJawad Great! Thanks for telling me.